# PIP3 import error cannot import name 'load_entry_point' from 'pkg_resources' (unknown location)

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, pip

I have installed pip3 using below commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

The commands run perfectly well with no error. However when i do below to check pip version:

```
$ pip3 -v
```

It gives error import error: cannot import name 'load_entry_point' from 'pkg_resources'

**System**: Virtual box version 6.1.2, **OS**: Ubuntu version 20.04, **Python** version **3.8.2**

So I suspect pip3 is may be not properly installed...How to install it if not installed?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with steps. But if we are getting error like above, then we need to be able to resolve that error. I just rebooted my system, restarted everything. Sometimes its the problem with servers.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

and finally did

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

And it worked